# How to check if text in asp.net textbox is selected with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I was wondering if this is at all possible, I want to check whether a user has selected text inside a textbox control, just like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001608/how-to-know-if-the-text-in-a-textbox-is-selected) (but this is just for html input controls and not asp.net server controls)

Comment: Don't be surprised to much but behind the scene almost all asp.net controls rendering to html controls. So you absolutely free to use solution you referring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `nothing to change` for server control `except the syntax` as far as that example is concerned.

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" value="Selected?"><asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="alert(isTextSelected();" ></asp:Button>

    function isTextSelected() {
input = document.getElementById('<%= test.ClientID %>'))
        if (typeof input.selectionStart == "number") {
            return input.selectionStart == 0 && input.selectionEnd == input.value.length;
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
            input.focus();
            return document.selection.createRange().text == input.value;
        }
    }
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using

```
$('select, input').click(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('disabled');
});
```