# Wrap an html tag after clicking a toolbar button using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do something similar to what this website and wordpress does. When a user highlights text on the screen, then clicks a button on the toolbar it will wrap an html tag around the text. In jquery I would probably use the .wrap class but how would I detect if the user highlighted something.

For example, when the user writes `Hello World` then clicks on the bold button it will say `<b>Hello World</b>`

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001608/how-to-know-if-the-text-in-a-textbox-is-selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mainly requires (1) accessing the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)/[textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) element and (2) replacing the substring of the `value` property across that range with the same text, but wrapped in the desired start and end tags. Also, I think it makes sense to reselect the replaced text, which requires a couple of calls to `select()` and `setSelectionRange()`. Also, if there's no selection (meaning start equals end) it's probably a good idea to do nothing at all.

```js
window.selWrapBold = function(id) { selWrap(id,'<b>','</b>'); };
window.selWrapItalic = function(id) { selWrap(id,'<i>','</i>'); };
window.selWrap = function(id,startTag,endTag) {
    let elem = document.getElementById(id);
    let start = elem.selectionStart;
    let end = elem.selectionEnd;
    let sel = elem.value.substring(start,end);
    if (sel==='') return;
    let replace = startTag+sel+endTag;
    elem.value =  elem.value.substring(0,start)+replace+elem.value.substring(end);
    elem.select();
    elem.setSelectionRange(start,start+replace.length);
} // end selWrap()
```

```html
<input type="button" value="bold" onclick="selWrapBold('ta1');"/>
<input type="button" value="italic" onclick="selWrapItalic('ta1');"/>
<br/>
<textarea id="ta1"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the text of the html element which is wrapping the text, then add as html the text embedded in the `<b>` tag.

See [jQuery DOM Manipulation](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_get.asp) for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) question to get the selected text. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636919/how-can-i-get-the-element-in-which-highlighted-text-is-in) question to 
  get the element with selected text in it. I combined them in a single function.

```
function updateHighlightedText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString(); 
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    var node = $(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode); //Get the selected node
    node.html(node.text().replace(text, "<b>"+text+"</b>")); //Update the node
}
```